# Resource and useful tips on Transfer Learning in NLP

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word-embeddings, convolutional-neural-network, transfer-learning

I have a few label data for training and testing a DNN. Main purpose of my work is to train a model which can do a binary classification of text. And for this purpose, I have around 3000 label data and 60000 unlabeled data available to me. My data type is related to instructions (like- open the door[label-1], give me a cup of water[label-1], give me money[label-0] etc.) In this case, I heard that Transferring knowledge from other models will help me a lot. Can anyone give me some useful resource for transfer learning in NLP domain?

I already did a few experiments. I used GLoVE as a pretrained embeddings. Then test it with my label data. But got around 70% accuracy. Also tried with embedding built using my own data (63k) and then train the model. Got 75% accuracy on the test data. My model architecture is given below-
[image]

**Q1:** I have a quick question will it be referred to as Transfer learning if I use GLOVE embeddings in model?

Any kind of help is welcomed. Even someone has other ideas for building a model without using transfer learning is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use pre-trained models on data that are distinct from the data they were originally trained on, it's transfer learning. Your two-class sentence corpus is distinct from the data that the GloVe embeddings were generated on, so this could be considered a form of transfer learning. [This might be a helpful explainer](http://ruder.io/transfer-learning/index.html#whatistransferlearning) for general ideas around pre-training (and why it's a worthy pursuit).

Recent work in the NLP transfer learning space that I'm aware of is [ULMFiT by Howard and Ruder of fast.ai](http://nlp.fast.ai/classification/2018/05/15/introducting-ulmfit.html), here's [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06146) if you prefer that. OpenAI also has recent work extending the Transformer model with a [unsupervised pre-training, task specific fine-tuning approach.](https://blog.openai.com/language-unsupervised/)

As for your task, I think it might be helpful to explore research around sentence classification rather than digging deeply into transfer learning. For your purposes, it seems that embeddings are a means to have a reasonable representation of your data rather than prove that Common Crawl (or some other dataset) extends to your corpus.

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: Your comments are really helpful. Yes I am aware of fast.ai. 
I was also thinking of using sentence classification without using transfer learning. Also, getting around 87~90% accuracy without using TL. Do you think it is reasonable accuracy in case of training 673606 params with around 3k label data?

Comment: I don't know enough about the data, difficulty of the task, or the final application of what you're working on to have a well-founded answer for you.